# How do i add more than one uriVariable to the Resttemplate exchange() function

Tags: java, spring, parameters, resttemplate

I am consuming Gitlab's API, for some endpoints you have two variable e.g  https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:id/members/:user_id
projectId and userId are variables I want to add to the url.

I am trying to use more than one uriVariables in the restTemplate exchange().

I have been doing this when i have one variable

```
  @Override
    public User getUser(String userId){
        ResponseEntity<User> respEntity = restTemplate.exchange(userURL, HttpMethod.GET,getHeader(), User.class, userId );

        User user = respEntity.getBody();

        return user;
    }
```

userURL=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/{userid}

Now doing this for two variables

```
 @Override
        public User getUserFromProject(String userId, String projectId){
            ResponseEntity<User> respEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET,getHeader(), User.class, projectId,userId );

            User user = respEntity.getBody();

            return user;
        }
```

URL=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{projectId}/members/{userId}

Throws this Error

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest:
>   400 Bad Request   at
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:79)
>   ~[spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]

Thanks.

Comment: Build the URL before adding it the `exchange` method

Comment: Thanks i tried that, it did not work but i later realized  i am setting wrong a content in the header.